# How to put content under fixed header or nav when opened in browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello I have problem when I make header using html and css. I have my header in fixed position, but the content is covered up my header. I want my content position under header when I run it. One more, I set header width 100% but it shift to the right so it doesn't cover up whole width on the screen.
[UPDATED]

[image]

```css
<style>
@media(min-width: 468px) {
    body{
        background-color: aqua;
    }
    .container-1{
           display: flex; 
           /*
           align-items: flex-start;  -->box 1 lebih sempit ke atas
           align-items: flex-end;  -->box 1 lebih sempit ke bawah
           align-items: center;  -->box 1 lebih sempit ke tengah (atas bawah)
           flex-direction: column; -->flex box menjadi kolom
           */
        }
        .container-2{
            display: flex;
            /*
            justify-content: flex-end;
            justify-content: flex-start;
            */
            justify-content: space-between; /*ada spasi diantara kotak*/
        }
}
       .container-3{
           display: flex;
           flex-wrap: wrap;
       }
        
        .container-1 div, .container-2 div, .container-3 div{
            border:1px #000000 solid;
            padding:10px;
        }
        
        .box-1{
        flex:2;
        order:2;
        
        }
        .box-2{
            flex:1;
            order:1;
        }
        .box-3{
            flex: 1;
            order:3;
        }

        .container-2-box{
            flex-basis:20%;
        }

        .container-3-box{
            flex-basis: 10%;
            
        }
        header{
            padding: 0.5rem;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
            background-color: beige;
           position: fixed;
            width: 100%;
            margin:0;
   
        }
        .whole-container{
            margin-top:2.0rem;
            
        }
        </style>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Flexbox</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1> Flexbox</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="whole-container">
    <div class="container-1"> 
        <div class="box-1">
            <h3>Box 1</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box-2">
            <h3>Box 2</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box-3">
            <h3>Box 3</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-2"> 
        <div class="container-2-box">
            <h3>Box 4</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="container-2-box">
            <h3>Box 5</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="container-2-box">
            <h3>Box 6</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-3"> 
        <div class="container-3-box">
            <h3>Box 7</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="container-3-box">
            <h3>Box 8</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="container-3-box">

            <h3>Box 9</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="container-3-box">
            <h3>Box 10</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="container-3-box">
            <h3>Box 11</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="container-3-box">
            <h3>Box 12</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add some HTML to your snippet to reproduce the issue.

Comment: hi please add html to help you

Comment: I have added html source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your HTML code it is a bit guessing, but I'll give it a go.

Adding a `position: fixed` to an element will make it flow above the other content. The element is taken out of the document flow. So the overlapping is natural behavior.

To prevent the content to be hidden, you should add a padding to the parent of the boxes. I'm guessing that when you add the following code, it solves the problem

```
body {
   padding-top: 3rem; /* should be at least the height of the header*/
}
```

The second question about the position of the header can be fixed by the following code:

```
/* option 1, add a left position:*/
header {
   ... 
   left: 0;
}

/* option 2, remove the width, use left and right position instead: */
header {
   ... 
   /* width: 100%; remove this line */
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
}
```

Comment: I have follow you instruction, and edit it a bit. I give .whole-container padding-top: 5.0 rem and header top:0;. Result, header become 100% wide and no space above it. The content isn't covered up anymore by header. Thank you very much

Comment: Yeah, I had to guess it. That's why I wrote "the parent of the boxes", which was in your case `.whole-container`. Good to hear you got it working. Good luck with the rest of your project.

Answer (score 0):

`body {
  margin: 0;
}`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  background-color: beige;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  /*not cover whole width*/
  margin: 0;
}

.whole-container {
  margin-top: 2.0rem;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    0000
  </header>

</body>
```